# Best way to push a new commit to already existing branch with new changes from master branch in git

Tags: git, merge, branch, commit, git-pull

I am new to Git and wanted to understand the best way to push things.
I have 2 branches. One is master and other is my feature branch.

I worked on master branch and followed the below commands to push to master branch:

```
Had few changes on master branch.

On master:
git stash save -u "some-msg"
git pull
git stash pop (no conflicts)
git checkout -b feature

On feature feature:
git push --set-upstream origin feature
git push
```

Few commits are added to master branch and also feature branch by others. Now I made some more changes in feature branch and I wanted to have my feature branch in sync with master. I wanted to know what is the best way to do it without diverging from origin/feature.

```
On feature branch:

option1: (have new changes in feature branch)
git stash save -u "new commit"
git pull (to get new commits from feature branch)
git pull origin master (to get commits from master)
git stash pop
git push

option 2: (have new changes in feature branch)
git pull --rebase
git pull origin master
git push
```

Any other good ways are highly appreciated!

Comment: "Best" is virtually always a matter of opinion (and thus off topic for StackOverflow by definition). For learning Git, however, I recommend that you *avoid* `git pull`. It really just runs two *other* Git commands for you, and you should first learn each of those commands separately, and get to know them well, before you start using the all-in-one "do everything all at once" operation. There are a number of reasons for this, but the simplest and perhaps most convincing one is: each of the two steps *can* fail. The recovery for a failure is *different* depending on *which step failed*.

Comment: If all you know is "git pull" you won't even know which part failed, much less be able to pick the right recovery step!

Answer (score 0):

First, rebase your local feature branch with origin/feature

```
git pull origin feature --rebase
```

If any conflicts, resolve.

Now, rebase your local feature branch with origin/master

```
git pull origin master --rebase
```

If any conflicts, resolve.

Now, push your feature branch.